# Control Alsa in real time with external controller?

Tags: sound, alsa, midi, realtime

Okay so after hunting down old threads and questions, I feel it's best to just ask this and see if I can get some help. My question is how in the world do I control Alsa externally with my [Korg micro controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8LUA.jpg)?

If anyone can help me or guide me in a better direction, that would be very much appreciated. The closest thread I found to my question is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2202049). It somewhat helped, however It still doesent cover exactly what I'm trying to do.
For future reference: I am NOT making music, I just want to be able to control my I/O audio with ease using a psychical controller (like korg) in real time.

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean with "control ALSA". Do you want to change mixer controls?

Comment: If possible I'd like to use my Korg to control the volume of all my sound. It sounds simple, but again I've yet to find any leads..

Comment: See [Retrieving Output From A Command Streaming Information](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16878728/11654), but call `amixer` instead.